# Remap a key combination to another combination, e. g. Super+Ctrl+Shift+J -> Ctrl+Shift+Left

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb

I want to implement an addition key layer, so that I can access non-alphanumeric keys without having to move my wrists.

I've been using Autokey for this purpose, but the experience was unsatisfactory: it had occasional lags and let original keystrokes slip into certain apps.

So I need a low-level solution.

Comment: you might have to create custom virtual input driver to do this which i would guess would be written in C

Comment: @Amias, can you please elaborate?

Comment: you could have a xinput driver that runs the normal keyboard driver but interprets the keystrokes before passing them on to xorg , this would give you complete control but would be a moderately complex couple of days work for a C programmer.

Answer (score 13):

Give a combination of [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) and [xvkbd](http://t-sato.in.coocan.jp/xvkbd/) a try. `xbindkeys` listens for the keys and sends the translation to xvkbd.

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xvkbd
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Open `.xbindkeysrc` in your favourite editor. I commented everything else out, but it's good to refer to if required.

To check it out, I tried mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\Cv""
   control + semicolon
```

I expect you're after something like this:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\C\S\[Left]""
  Super+Control+Shift+J
```

Save the file, then run `xbindkeys`.

In order to reload any configuration changes, I killed the `xbindkeys` process then restarted.

### xbindkeys syntax

I worked out the key combination by using a GUI for `xbindkeys`

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
xbindkeys-config
```

Once you run that, press Get Key for the combination to put into the second line of your `.xbindkeysrc` file.

### xvkbd syntax

From the manual:

```
\r - Return
\t - Tab
\b - Backspace
\e - Escape
\d - Delete
\S - Shift (modify the next character; please note that modify with ``\S'' will be ignored in many cases. For example, ``a\Cb\ScD\CE'' will be interpreted as a, Control-b, c, Shift-D, and Control-Shift-E.)
\C - Control (modify the next character)
\A - Alt (modify the next character)
\M - Meta (modify the next character)
\[keysym] - the keysym keysym (e.g., \[Left]), which will be processed in the similar matter with other general characters
\{keysym} - the keysym keysym (e.g., \{Left}), which will be processed in more primitive matter and can also be used for modofier keys such as Control_L, Meta_L, etc.; also, \{+keysym} and \{+keysym} will simulate press and release of the key, respectively [Version 3.3]
\Ddigit - delay digit * 100 ms
\xvalue - move mouse pointer (use "+" or "-" for relative motion)
\yvalue - move mouse pointer (use "+" or "-" for relative motion)
\mdigit - simulate click of the specified mouse button
```

Love to hear how it works out and if the combination was fit for your purpose. It looks good as a keymapper, but not necessarily a macro runner.

Comment: Hey @MarkHewitt! Thank you so much for the detailed response! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me very well: the original keypress keeps coming through, which ruins the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the solution here (because Xorg is the low-level-est layer...): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg

EDIT: for what I've understood you need to add the option `lv3:win_switch` in your .conf file

Comment: I need a specific example.

Comment: [*Clears throat*](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15151/please-do-not-use-links-as-entire-answers) ***;)***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

You can use it for the exact behavior of your titles example, but for simplicity, I the follwing just uses `space` to activate a movement layer if something else is pressed while `space` is held down, else it inserts a space.

After installation, use the config below:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

# set the behavior of space (you could also use a timeout):
space = overload(spacemove,space)

# this defines the space layer, the function of keys when space is held
# all non-described keys act as in the layer [main]
[spacemove]
i = up
k = down 
j = left
l = right
```

keyd is very versatile, stable and fast.